# How do I return the most similar Unicode character to a section of an image?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, unicode, ascii

I made a simple converter in Python to convert images to ASCII. Right now it uses various shades of dark characters, so it works but it is hard to make out at low resolutions: for example, the Google logo comes out as:

```
  ..  .;.                  .@      
 a;       .. .;     . .. a. @ ...;.
 aa    .a.▒.  ▒.;.  ;.;; a. ▒ @a   
  .;.. .; .....  .    ..;;; ;  ;.. 
                     .a. .;
```

This can barely be made out. Is there a way that I could compare each section to a subset of Unicode characters and return the most similar, so it could return for example something like:

```
  ./--.\.                  /▒      
 a;       ./-.;  /  \ ./ \\ ▒ ./━\.
 aa    -a.▒.  ▒.|.  |.;▒  ┃ ▒ ▒-~┘ 
  \;.. /| \\_//  \ /  .\;;; ▒ \\.- 
                     .pp--▒
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Generate an image for each character you'd like to use, in the font which you'll be using. You will probably use a fixed width font which will make it possible to create one large image and break it up later. This might be as easy as typing the characters into an editor and doing a screen capture.
2. For each patch of the input image, compare the patch to all of the character images. I would take corresponding pixels from the patch and the character and square the difference, and sum them up - the character with the lowest sum is the one that most closely matches the patch.

You might improve the results by doing a blur on the character images, the input image, or both. You also might get better results by increasing the contrast on the input image.

Another idea to improve both result quality and speed would be to calculate the average darkness of each character, and only attempt to match characters that are nearly the same darkness as the patch.

Comment: Is there a way to use the fonts directly without screen captures? If I understand correctly there are something like 65,536 characters in UTF-8.

Comment: @user677624 Not all of the UTF-8 characters are printable or meant to be used alone, and very few fonts will contain more than just the European characters. When you said "subset" in the question I thought you were going to pare it down to a reasonable number. I know PIL can generate text images but I haven't been able to figure out how to use system fonts with it.

Comment: Well, I want to include [shape drawing characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_characters) as well as just the regular ones, so as to be able to represent it more accurately.

Comment: Mark: Most (serious) fonts actually should contain at least Latin, Greek and Cyrillic as well as the usual assortment of diacritics, punctuation, arrows and dingbats.

Comment: I hope to find an article where just this type of algorithm was described, you gave it list of bitmapped characters, it would then match each image block to the closest similar looking character shape. Worked really well for lineart.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread, but I might as well add my solution here. You can use braille characters to get pixel-perfect representations. Like so:

`⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⡿⡻⡫⡫⡣⣣⢣⢇⢧⢫⢻⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⡟⡟⣝⣜⠼⠼⢚⢚⢚⠓⠷⣧⣇⠧⡳⡱⣻⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⡟⣏⡧⠧⠓⠍⡂⡂⠅⠌⠄⠄⠄⡁⠢⡈⣷⡹⡸⣪⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢿⠿⢿⢿⢿⢟⢏⡧⠗⡙⡐⡐⣌⢬⣒⣖⣼⣼⣸⢸⢐⢁⠂⡐⢰⡏⣎⢮⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣽⣾⣶⣿⢿⢻⡱⢕⠋⢅⠢⠱⢼⣾⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡇⡇⠢⢁⢂⡯⡪⣪⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢟⠏⢎⠪⠨⡐⠔⠁⠁⠀⠀⠀⠙⢿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢱⠡⡁⣢⢏⢮⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢟⢍⢆⢃⢑⠤⠑⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠙⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⡱⢑⢐⢼⢱⣵⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢿⢫⡱⢊⢂⢢⠢⡃⠌⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠘⣿⣿⢟⢑⢌⢦⢫⣪⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⡻⡱⡑⢅⢢⣢⣳⢱⢑⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠹⡑⡑⡴⡹⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢟⢝⠜⠨⡐⣴⣵⣿⣗⡧⡣⠢⢈⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣜⢎⣷⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⡫⡱⠑⡁⣌⣮⣾⣿⣿⣿⣟⡮⡪⡪⡐⠠⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟⢏⠜⠌⠄⣕⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣯⡯⣎⢖⠌⠌⠄⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢨⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢟⢕⠕⢁⠡⣸⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡽⡮⡪⡪⠨⡂⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢟⢕⠕⢁⢐⢔⣽⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢽⡱⡱⡑⡠⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣸⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢟⢕⠕⢁⢐⢰⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣟⣞⢜⠔⢄⠡⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣼⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⡹⡰⠃⢈⠠⣢⣿⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡮⣇⢏⢂⠢⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣠⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⢫⢒⡜⠐⠀⢢⣱⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣳⢕⢕⠌⠄⡀⠀⠀⢀⣤⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⡑⣅⠗⠀⡀⣥⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠟⢙⠙⠿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣯⢮⡪⣂⣢⣬⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⡟⡜⢌⡞⡀⣡⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⡿⠛⠉⢀⡠⠔⢜⣱⣴⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⡿⡸⡘⢜⣧⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⢛⡡⠤⡒⢪⣑⣬⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⡇⡇⡣⣷⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⠿⡛⡣⡋⣕⣬⣶⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣮⣺⣿⣿⣟⣻⣩⣢⣵⣾⣾⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿⣿
⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿⠿`

I built a tool for this in Go called dotmatrix: https://github.com/kevin-cantwell/dotmatrix

Comment: Thank you for posting this! Even if it was an old thread, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

When you say

> compare each section to a subset of Unicode

this is not really clear, because there is more than one way to do this. I would bring the comparing down to the level of pixel. In a gray image, every pixel has a gray-value. Assume you want to replace every pixel by an appropriate character, how *has this character to match the pixel*? If you look at a character from really far, you'll see only a gray spot. If you replace now a pixel with a character, you should choose the character with the most similar gray-value to that pixel.

In a monospaced font, every character uses the same amount of space. If you take now this rectangle of space, draw a character on it, you can calculate the *mean gray-value*. This mean gray-value is not more than how much area of the rectangle is white compared to the whole rectangle. A *space* has a gray-value of 1. And maybe a dollar-sign is one of the most black characters you'll find.

So here is what I would do:

1. Take a set of characters, no matter whether you use only ascii or uni-code. Calculate for every character the amount of white. It should be obvious, that this could be different for different fonts, but you have to use a monospaced one.
2. You have now a list which maps every character to a gray-value. You should now rescale the gray-values to your target gray-value interval. When you have an 8-bit image, then your brightest character (space) should correspond to a value of 255 and your darkest should correstpond to gray-level 0.
3. Now, rescale your input image, so that it is not too big, because even with a very small font, you'll maybe not getting 2000 characters on one line.
4. Replace every pixel with the character whose gray-level is nearest to its own graylevel

In Mathematica this is only a few lines of code. In python it's maybe a bit longer, but it should be ok too.

Using this way, you get pretty amazing results when you look at the *text* from far away and when you get closer, you see that it all consists of characters.

[image: House in ascii 1]

[image: House in ascii 1]

[image: House in ascii 1]

---

### Update

When you want to create an image of the same size as the original, then the approach is not very different but even here you have, as Mark already pointed out, to create a raster image of every letter you are using. 
I don't really see a faster way of comparing your image-tiles with a letter to decide which one is the most appropriate.

**Maybe one hint:** If your using this approach, the letters will be visible in your image, because when you have e.g. a 12pt font, each letter will have at least an image-size of about 10x15. When you now convert an image of 1000x1500, which is not so small, you use only 100x100 letters.
Therefore, it might be worth a thought to *not* use the image itself but the image gradients. This may give better images, because then a letter is choosen, which follows the edges quite good. 
Using only the gradients, the google logo doesn't look so bad

[image: ascii google logo]

Comment: Yes, but I want to generate ASCII art which is "the same size" as the original image (see my first post) - this method creates absolutely enormous text files, which cannot be displayed on a single page.

Comment: This works on medium-size images, but for small ones the gradients are smaller than individual characters.

Comment: That's not a problem of the images, but of how you rasterize every single letter. The raster-size of your alphabet has to be appropriate for the image you are using.
And btw, if you think your gradients are too small, why don't you dilate them?

Comment: I can't change the way the letters are rasterized, because it's printing to a terminal.